# Override the DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE with MEDIA_URL to integrate Azure CDN

Tags: django, azure

I'm using Azure Storage account for storing my media files

Setting it is simple in settings.py like this:

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.azure_storage.AzureStorage'
AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME = 'my_account_name'
AZURE_ACCOUNT_KEY = 'my_account_key'
AZURE_CONTAINER = 'my-container'
```

However, I considered later that I want to use Azure CDN instead for serving my media files. How will I point it to the CDN URL instead? I tried setting it in the MEDIA_URL like

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'upload')
MEDIA_URL = '//my-media.azureedge.net/my-container/'
```

However my storage-account blob is the one being shown as default URL which is 'xxxxx.blob.core.windows.net' instead of my MEDIA URL..

How will I show the MEDIA_URL instead of 'xxxxx.blob.core.windows.net'?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by `How will I show the MEDIA_URL instead of 'xxxxx.blob.core.windows.net'?`. Where do you want to show this?

Comment: in django-admin, the link of the uploaded file when you are trying to update or the return of the link on the returned response of a django-rest-framework viewset

Comment: It this for your development environment or production server?

Comment: @dentemm, production server

Answer (score 1):

Thankfully I already have an answer for this one. You need to override the storage backend class of Azure on the 'storages' library replacing the blob hostname with the CDN hostname.

settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '//my-media.azureedge.net/my-container/'
```

storages.py

```
import re
from jaguar import settings
from storages.backends.azure_storage import AzureStorage


class AzureCDNURL(AzureStorage):

    def url(self, name):
        ret = super(AzureCDNURL, self).url(name)
        _ret = re.sub('//[a-z.0-9A-Z]*/', settings.MEDIA_URL, ret)
        return _ret
```